# QSqlQuery constructor strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt5

QMake version 3.0

Qt version 5.0.2

When using

```
QSqlQuery query(QString("SELECT device_text_id FROM device"));
qDebug() << query.exec();
```

i get false in query.exec() and no results returned in query object but when I use

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT device_text_id FROM device");
qDebug() << query.exec();
```

i get true and correct data returned.

In [documentation of QSqlQuery](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquery.html) is a constructor beeing used in both of cases above:

```
QSqlQuery(const QString & query = QString(), QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
```

For more info I checked my postgres (v9.1) logs. I hit this error every time the query is executed in the first way presented.

```
CET ERROR:  syntax error at end of input at character 9
CET STATEMENT:  EXECUTE
```

Am I missing something? Why the first approach is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the constructor with a string directly executes that query. The query already got executed once the object is constructed.

When you then call `.exec()`, it tries to execute a query that got prepared with `prepare()`. But there was no `prepare()`, so that attempt fails. This failure causes the return value `false` that you see in the program.

Comment: so how can I bind values if I try the first approach? Is it only possible when using prepare?